# Insert text between html tag using regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I want to insert `&nbsp` between empty paragraph tags.

**Input:**

```
1. <div><p></p></div>
2. <div><p style="margin: 0 0 0 0"></p></div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
1. <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
2. <div><p style="margin: 0 0 0 0">&nbsp;</p></div>
```

I tried to use look behind and forward but apparently I can't use quantifier here:  `(?<=< p[^>]*>)(?=<\/p>)`

Any ideas? My available tools are regex and c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be overthinking. I think all you need is to simply replace `></p>` with `>&nbsp;</p>`, isn't it?

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("></p>", ">&nbsp;</p>");
```

**EDIT**

If you must use RegEx, then you do like this:

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "(<p[^>]*>)(</p>)", "$1&nbsp;$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: with your first suggestion <p><span></span></p> will also get replaced, i am looking into your second option, what does the $1 $2 do?

Answer (score 0):

Get all paragraphs tag and check their inner text if empty.

If its empty do something like `getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML= '&nbsp';`

Comment: i can't use javascript for this one. this is basically a xaml file converted to html, and I am trying to get rid of some noise

Comment: Oops, well then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32362354/810610) answer should be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=>)(\s*)(?=<\/p>)
```